# How to upload image on AWS S3 using AdminBro on and Express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, admin

How to upload an image on AWS S3 using AdminBro. I am trying to upload an image to AWS S3, and I am using Nodejs, Expressjs, and AdminBro.

I have tried but unfortunately, it's not working and I don't know what else to do to make it work.

I think one of my main challenges now is what to put inside listProperties. Also, I discovered that the `Program` form showed double fields for image upload, one in upload format and another in the input format. How do I make it to show only upload format, only?

The `Program` is showing `500 Error` when I try to create it.
I followed this documentation https://adminbro.com/module-@admin-bro_upload.html but I am not doing it right.

```
const AdminBro = require("admin-bro");
const AdminBroExpress = require("admin-bro-expressjs");
const AdminBroMongoose = require("admin-bro-mongoose");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Program = require("../models/program");
AdminBro.registerAdapter(AdminBroMongoose);
const uploadFeature = require("@admin-bro/upload");

const fs = require("fs");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

AWS.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRECT,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.S3_REGION,
});

var region = process.env.S3_REGION;
var bucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;

const uploadPath = path.join("public", Program.programImageBasePath);
const imageMineTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];

s3 = new AWS.S3();
 const upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    acl: "public-read",
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    s3BucketEndpoint: true,
    endpoint: "http://" + process.env.S3_BUCKET + ".s3.amazonaws.com",
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uploadPathWithOriginalName = uploadPath + "/" + file.originalname;
      cb(null, uploadPathWithOriginalName);
     },
   }),
});

const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  databases: [mongoose],
  rootPath: "/admin",
  resources: [
    {
      resource: Program,
         options: {
        listProperties: ["what should i put here?", imageMineTypes],
      },
      features: [
        uploadFeature({
          provider: { aws: { region, bucket, secretAccessKey } },
          properties: {
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
              const uploadPathWithOriginalName =
                uploadPath + "/" + file.originalname;
              cb(null, uploadPathWithOriginalName);
            }, // to this db field feature will safe S3 key
            mimeType: imageMineTypes, // this property is important because allows to have 
            previews
          },
          validation: {
            mimeTypes: "application/pdf",
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
  ],
});

const router = AdminBroExpress.buildRouter(adminBro);

module.exports = router;
```